# What driver used for connection to IBM Db2 with selected item 'Driver/Microsoft(requires .Net 4.5 or later' from Excel Data menu)?

Tags: excel, vba, db2

I can receive data from IBM Db2 into EXCEL via Driver named as 'Microsoft' from EXCEL menu Data/Get Data/From Database/From IBM Db2 Database/Advanced options.

What driver is used to establish connection to Db2 in this case?

How to establish such connection from VBA?

In case IBM driver selected VBA code can be like:

```
Dim conn As Object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver=IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;Protocol=TCPIP;Hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=9999;Database=xxx"
```

What I need to specify in ConnectionString corresponding to Driver Microsoft?[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5MaP.jpg)

Comment: Why not use a DSN, and instead of having a connection-string, just use `conn.open` on the DSN ?

Comment: You can not open any connection without definition. Before use DSN you must define it with Windows ODBC Administrator or any other tool and only after this you can use it. The question is what need to be defined but not how to use it.